# After hiding game scene, previous view not visible

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ios6

I am developing a cocos2d game in ios. 
This is the code for app delegate :

```
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.homeViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.homeViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

In this I am making the `ViewController` class the `rootViewController`.
And I am presenting `GameOptionsViewController` class from `HomeViewController` class.
From `GameOptionsViewController` I am calling the method in app delegate to add the game scene.

```
-(void)addGameScene

    {

    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    if( ! [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] )
        [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeMainLoop];
    else {
        [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink];
    }

    // Init the View Controller
    viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    if(!glView)
        glView = [[EAGLView alloc] initWithFrame:[window bounds]];
    [director setOpenGLView:glView];

    [director setOpenGLView:glView];
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    [viewController setView:glView];
    [window setRootViewController:viewController];
    [window addSubview: viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: [HelloWorldLayer scene]];
}
```

Now when i want to hide the game scene, i use the code:

```
   [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
   [[CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView setHidden:YES];
```

The game scene is hidden, but the previous view, i.e `GameOptionsViewController` does not show up.
What I am doing wrong??.. Please advice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you set the RootViewController with viewController like that..

```
[window setRootViewController:viewController];
```

as it just set your `GameOptionsViewController` class object as a rootViewController..

For Ex.

```
   ViewController *homeViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
   window.rootViewController = homeViewController;
```

i hope this help you...

Comment: So you want to say that when I call the method to add t he game scene, there i make the gameOptionsViewController to rootViewController..

Comment: yes bcoz i think here you set the RootViewController as a windows rootViewController without nib so just try to just swap the rootViewController with your gameOptionsViewController or homeViewControler like in you post the code in first section ..

Comment: I just replaced the `viewController` with my `HomeViewController` while setting the `RootViewController` and it worked.. Thanks Man..